# Google app engine, datetime: calculate time length

Tags: google-app-engine, datetime

Regarding time zones, what is the best way to correctly calculate the time length using:

```
timeLength = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) - datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: This question makes no sense. Length of what? And this appears to be a general Python question, not a GAE one.

Comment: @Daniel: length of "time" -- how long is it from now to the beginning of the year 2012. The calculation has no problem under Python environment. However, if you're on the Google App Engine, the time is in UTC format, and the length of time will be wrong depending on what time zone you're in. To be specific, my question is: how to adjust "datetime.datetime.now()" according to the time zone. Perhaps "datetime.datetime.now(tz='Asia/Taipei')"? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this link http://timezones.appspot.com/

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(raw_timestamp, utc) #might help
```

as well python:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import calendar 
calendar.timegm(pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam').localize(datetime.strptime('2012-12-21 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).utctimetuple())
```

Comment: Thanks JimmyKane, I'll give a try.